Additive functor category has a generator
In the Wikipedia page for Grothendieck categories, one example that's given is the category of additive functors from a small additive category $\mathcal C$ to a Grothendieck category $\mathcal A$. However, when I look at the source given, they seem to argue that the generator for this category should be something of the form
$$\coprod_{c \in \mathcal C} h^{c}$$
for some form of Yoneda functor $h^c$. This doesn't make sense to me because I don't see a way to get a construction like the Yoneda functor to land in $\mathcal A$. Any advice on constructing a generator?

If $C$ is a category and $D$ is a category with a generator object $G$ and which has coproducts, you can easily verify that the $\hom(c,-) \otimes G$ form a generating set of $[C,D]$. Here, $\otimes$ denotes the copower / external tensor product. If $C$ is small it follows that their coproduct is a generator object.

Could you say a little about how to construct this copower? I'm unfamiliar with the concept and it's unclear to me from the general definition what it's supposed to mean in this context.
